Issue: C.proofSize.toBn is not a function on block number
I encountered an error when using the Polkadot.js UI. When I click on a link, the following error appears:
Uncaught error. Something went wrong with the query and rendering of this component. Please supply all the details below when logging an issue, it may help in tracing the cause
**C.proofSize.toBn is not a function**
TypeError: C.proofSize.toBn is not a function
at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/page.d47f234fff7c6edc.js:835:7858
at _i (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:77446)
at Ol (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:89067)
at _l (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:88275)
at El (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:87880)
at _u (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:137602)
at ws (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:123430)
at ys (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:123358)
at vs (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:123221)
at is (https://polkadot.js.org/apps/modu.bd8f3266470441f0.js:2:120028)
Steps to reproduce:
Open the Polkadot.js UI.
Click on the block number from explorer menu.
Observe the error.
This seems to be related to C.proofSize.toBn not being recognized as a function.
Here is a link for reference: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.3dpscan.io#/explorer/query/0x18225ad45be17612ec535080cdaf74776bb827a38f525f51e791dba4de959d47
Any guidance or fixes for this would be appreciated!
